# Changing size of a textbox in html string in React

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm using a popup library sweetalert2-react-content to generate a popup box which contains a textbox and a textarea.  In the popupbox I am generating an html string to create the textbox and text area.  It's generating those elements just fine, however I am unable to change the size of the textarea.  Here's a code snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content';

submitButton() {

    const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal)

    MySwal.fire({
        confirmButtonText: 'Submit Post',
        showCancelButton: true,
        title: "Submit a new Post",
        html:
            '<br /><br />' +
            '<h4>Enter the title</h4>' +
            '<input type="text" id="theTitle">' +
            '<h4>Enter the body</h4>' +
            '<textarea rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>',
        input: 'file',
        focusConfirm: false,
      }).then(result => this.getPostValues(result.value))
    }
```

Any ideas how I might be able to get the textbox to display a little larger?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<textarea>` is likely controlled via the library's css so even if you set `rows` and `cols`, the css dictates styling. If so, you'll have to either edit the library's css, override it with your own css, or give it an inline `style`.

```
MySwal.fire({
    // Other settings...
    html:
        '...other html' +
       '<textarea style="height: 200px; width: 400px"></textarea>'
});
```

Comment: Perfect, you nailed it